# Python Pandas List() vs [] Behavior in isin()

Tags: python, pandas

Why do the following two code snippets produce different results?

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series(['abc','abcq', 'foo', 'baz'])
s.isin(['abc'])
```

vs

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series(['abc','abcq', 'foo', 'baz'])
s.isin(list('abc'))
```

Comment: `list('abc')` returns `['a','b','c']`, not `['abc']`.

Comment: If you want `[abc]`, the first method you've written is the only thing you need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series(['abc','abcq', 'foo', 'baz'])
print s.isin(['abc'])

print s.isin(list('abc'))

# why?
print list('abc')
```

output:

```
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 1):

Just take a look at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=list#list) for `list`:

> *class* list([*iterable*])
>
> Return a list whose items are the same and in the same order as *iterable*‘s items.
>   ...
>    For instance, `list('abc')` returns `['a', 'b', 'c']` and `list( (1, 2, 3) )` returns `[1, 2, 3]`.

You see when `list()` is given `'abc'`, it returns `['a', 'b', 'c']` because even a string is an iterable.  Just as `list(('a', 'b', 'c'))` becomes `['a', 'b', 'c']`, when the iterable is a string instead, `list()` splits up the string into individual characters. Using `['abc']`, however, you create a list with one element: a string.

Answer (score 0):

The first example return a boolean Series showing whether each element in the Series is exactly contained in `['abc']`.

The second test whether each element in the Series is exactly contained in `['a', 'b', 'c']` this is because `list('abc')` yields `['a', 'b', 'c']` thus 
`s.isin(list('abc'))` is the same as `s.isin(['a', 'b', 'c'])` which is quite different from `s.isin(['abc'])`