# Difference between list() vs. [] when turning a set into a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, types

I read that "typecasting" using `list()` calls a function, whereas just using the square brackets `[]` is calling a literal—meaning `[]` is quicker.

But I recently discovered that there are more differences beyond just speed. I have a dictionary where the keys are ints and the values are some object I made, where the objects have a string corresponding to a university name.

I wanted the unique university names, and so I (proudly and hopefully Pythonically!) wrote:

`[set([entry[1].school for entry in entries.items()])]`

But this creates a list of a single element, and that element is a set. This is different than:

`list(set([entry[1].school for entry in entries.items()]))`

Which returns a list of strings—what I had expected with the first.

Can someone explain what exactly is going on between both lines?

Comment: I've seen this question asked before, but I'm tired and don't feel like looking for it. I'm sure you'd find it with a Google search.

Comment: Well, I thought the question was "what's the difference between [] and list()", but I thought it was the function call vs. literal distinction. I thought the set had something to do with it, so I wasn't sure at that point how to ask the question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23703109/5827958 is similar. That one's a little more complicated than this, but should have the answer you need.

Comment: It's not really useful to think of things as being typecast in Python. Also, to help make your list list-comprehension more Pythonic, you should unpack the arguments: `list(set([entry.school for _, entry in entries.items()]))` where I used the conventional `_` to unpack a throwaway variable. Although really, if you think about it, you just want `[entry.school for entry in entries.values()]`

Comment: It could be that I was remembering answering a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36316837/5827958

Comment: @juanpa: He's probably using a set to remove duplicates.

Comment: Googling this question's exact title with the addition of the word "python" produces many useful results. The linked duplicate is in the very first page of results.

Answer (score 4):

`list(x)` is converting `x` to a `list`, while `[x]` is creating a new list with a single member (`x`)

```
>>> list('test')
['t', 'e', 's', 't']
>>> ['test']
['test']
```

There is special syntax for [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) where the list has a for expression inside

```
squares = [x**2 for x in range(10)]
```

But it doesn't really type cast.

---

Regarding the set conversion `list(set(...))` this does create a new list but the members are taken by iterating through the set.

```
>>> set('test')
set(['s', 'e', 't']) # a test set
>>> list(set('test'))
['s', 'e', 't'] # create a list with members from set
>>> [set('test')]
[set(['s', 'e', 't'])] # create a list with a single member (which is the test set itself)
```

Comment: As stated in [answer], please avoid answering unclear, overly-broad, typo, unreproducible, or duplicate questions. Write-my-code requests and low-effort homework questions are off-topic for [so] and more suited to professional coding/tutoring services. Good questions adhere to [ask], include a [mcve], have research effort, and have the potential to be useful to future visitors. Answering inappropriate questions harms the site by making it more difficult to navigate and encouraging further such questions, which can drive away other users who volunteer their time and expertise.